# Best practice for React useState with objects?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

Unlike the `state` from classes, you are not limited to a single object. With `useState`, you can create separate values for each case like this:

```js
const [name, setName] = useState('John');
const [email, setEmail] = useState('john@example.com');
const [age, setAge] = useState(25);
```

But, I found this very dirty and prefer using only one `useState` initialized with an object:

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState(
  { name: 'John', email: 'john@example.com', age: 25 }
);
```

---

I understand that there is no strict limit and `useState` can store objects, but in **class components**, when you update state using `this.setState`, it is ***merged*** with the old one. With `useState`, the update function ***replaces*** the old state with a new one (there is no merging).

I frequently implemented like below:

```js
setUser(prevStat => ({
...prevState,
  name: 'Daniel'
}));
```

> If I'm correct, updating an object state will re-render all fields of the object state, which supposedly will be more expensive for the app?

- **Am I correct with this approach?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that, but it's not what the [official React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-using-multiple-state-variables) do or recommend. It's still a working and valid approach.

If you find yourself using a state object because there's a lot of state, or managing interactions gets complicated, it might be a good time to consider using a reducer with [`useReducer`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer). You can move the boilerplate and logic out of the immediate call-site and better retain overview over the relationship between properties of you state object. With a reducer you‘d just write `dispatch({ type: "SET_NAME", name: "Daniel" })`.

Having all the code that modifies your state in one place (the reducer) allows you to better reason over actions such as resetting the state.

The dispatch function returned by `useReducer` is also stable and well suited to be passed to child components, making it easier to refactor your component into smaller ones.

Comment: I guess I founded my next favourite hook, Thanks for the references!

Answer (score 1):

If im not mistaken, if you initialize the state as a component, and you update it, for example, with a useEffect, you re-render the whole component.If performance is what worries you, you can use variables as the values of the object, and update that variables.

Comment: You will want to re-render the component anyway. It's also not clear to me, what you mean with "variables", where would you store them?

Comment: I've never mentioned any "variables". But I get a pretty clear idea from @MoritzMahringer